# Validating Image Dimensions in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

This question have lots of answers on `JQuery` and `JavaScript`. And also some versions of `Angular`.

I tried lots of solutions but none of them work out.

I'm using `Angular 7` and  trying to validate the `Width` and `Height` of the Image Uploaded by the user.

Here's my `.html` code snippet:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="androidPhoneFile" class="upload-box" placeholder="Upload File" multiple="multiple" (change)="onAndroidPhoneChange($event)" formControlName="androidPhone" #androidPhonePhoto>
```

And here's my `.ts` component file:

```
AddFilesToFormData(event: any, fileName: string) {
const reader = new FileReader();
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  const height = img.height;
  const width = img.width;
  console.log('Width and Height', width, height);
};

img.src = event.target.files[0];
if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
  const [file] = event.target.files;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      this.formData.append(fileName, event.target.files[i]);
      this.numberOfPhotos++;
    }
  };
}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
AddFilesToFormData(event: any, fileName: string) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    for (const file of event.target.files) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result as string;
        img.onload = () => {
          const height = img.naturalHeight;
          const width = img.naturalWidth;
          console.log('Width and Height', width, height);
        };
      };
    }
  }
}
```

About the `for`: I recommend you to change it for something like that:

```
    for (const image of event.target.files) {
      this.formData.append(fileName, image);
      this.numberOfPhotos++;
    }
```

It's clearer.

Comment: What if I uploaded more than one image ?? In this case I will see the Width and Height of the Last Selected Image.

Comment: Since you used `img.src = event.target.files[0];` I thought you were uploading a single image. If you are uploading more than 1, you just need to play a bit with the code. I'll try now to modify it

Comment: I added a `for` but I couldn't test it (the previous code was tested indeed for one single image). I guess it will work. If it does not, you just need to manipulate it a bit or let me know it and I'll fix it